# Cider original gravity is 1.11. Why is it so high?

Tags: cider, original-gravity

Bought a Mangrove Jack's brewing kit and some strawberry and pear cider. The cider I bought is supposed to be 4.7% but after following the instructions exactly and checking that the hydrometer was calibrated correctly I read an OG of 1.11?? Why would my original gravity be so high and is this normal for a sweet cider?

Comment: 1.11 is more like wine than cider or beer. Did this brewing kit also include some fermentables? Even if that package of cider concentrate was replaced with pure sugar you'd still only be at 1.063 (including the recommended 1 kg of dextrose). Check that recipe again, I think. And double check your final volume.

Comment: Could you tell us what these instruction was? Or how much extract and how much water there was, and what's the final batch size? And if you added anything more than extract?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, but the most obvious (what I did on my first batch) - Are you sure you added ALL the water? Did you get the +- 21 liters of wort?

Otherwise: how cold was the sample you were measuring? The colder it is, the higher the hydrometer will read. You have to take readings at the temp that your hydrometer is calibrated to.

Or: Test your hydrometer in some tap water. it should read 0 or very close to 0.

Assuming you did not do a full boil: Did you take your sample BEFORE or AFTER you added the extra water?